# Swift AVFoundation timing info for audio measurements

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, avaudioengine

I am creating an application that will take an audio measurement by playing some stimulus data and recording the microphone input, and then analysing the data.

I am having trouble accounting for the time taken to initialise and start the audio engine, as this varies each time and is also dependant on the hardware used, etc.

So, I have an audio engine and have installed a Tap the hardware input, with input 1 being the microphone recording, and input 2 being a reference input (also from the hardware). The output is physically Y-Split and fed back into input 2.

The app initialises the engine, plays the stimulus audio plus 1 second of silence (to allow propagation time for the microphone to record the whole signal back), and then stop and close the engine.

I write the two input buffers as a WAV file so that I can import this into an an existing DAW. to visually examine the signals.  I can see that each time I take a measurement, the time difference between the two signals is different (despite the fact the microphone is not moved and the hardware has stayed the same).  I am assuming this is to do with the latency of the hardware, the time taken to initialise the engine and the way the divice distributes tasks.

I have tried to capture the absolute time using mach_absolute_time of the first buffer callback on each installTap function and subtracting the two, and I can see that this does vary quite a lot with each call:

```
class newAVAudioEngine{

    var engine = AVAudioEngine()
    var audioBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer()
    var running = true
    var in1Buf:[Float]=Array(repeating:0, count:totalRecordSize)
    var in2Buf:[Float]=Array(repeating:0, count:totalRecordSize)
    var buf1current:Int = 0
    var buf2current:Int = 0
    var in1firstRun:Bool = false
    var in2firstRun:Bool = false
    var in1StartTime = 0
    var in2startTime = 0

    func measure(inputSweep:SweepFilter) -> measurement {
        initializeEngine(inputSweep: inputSweep)
        while running == true {

        }
        let measureResult = measurement.init(meas: meas,ref: ref)
        return measureResult
    }

    func initializeEngine(inputSweep:SweepFilter)  {
        buf1current = 0
        buf2current = 0
        in1StartTime = 0
        in2startTime = 0
        in1firstRun = true
        in2firstRun = true
        in1Buf = Array(repeating:0, count:totalRecordSize)
        in2Buf = Array(repeating:0, count:totalRecordSize)
        engine.stop()
        engine.reset()
        engine = AVAudioEngine()

        let srcNode = AVAudioSourceNode { _, _, frameCount, AudioBufferList -> OSStatus in

            let ablPointer = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(AudioBufferList)

            if (Int(frameCount) + time) <= inputSweep.stimulus.count {

                for frame in 0..<Int(frameCount) {
                let value = inputSweep.stimulus[frame + time]
                    for buffer in ablPointer {
                        let buf: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Float> = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(buffer)
                        buf[frame] = value
                    }
                }
                time += Int(frameCount)
                return noErr
            } else {
                for frame in 0..<Int(frameCount) {
                    let value = 0
                    for buffer in ablPointer {
                        let buf: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Float> = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(buffer)
                        buf[frame] = Float(value)
                    }
                }
            }
            return noErr
        }

        let format = engine.outputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
        let stimulusFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: format.commonFormat,
        sampleRate: Double(sampleRate),
        channels: 1,
        interleaved: format.isInterleaved)

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord)

            let ioBufferDuration = 128.0 / 44100.0

            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setPreferredIOBufferDuration(ioBufferDuration)
        } catch {
            assertionFailure("AVAudioSession setup failed")
        }

    let input = engine.inputNode
    let inputFormat = input.inputFormat(forBus: 0)

    print("InputNode Format is \(inputFormat)")
    engine.attach(srcNode)
    engine.connect(srcNode, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: stimulusFormat)

    if internalRefLoop == true {
        srcNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: stimulusFormat, block: {(buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time: AVAudioTime!) -> Void in
            if self.in2firstRun == true {
                var info = mach_timebase_info()
                mach_timebase_info(&info)
                let currentTime = mach_absolute_time()
                let nanos = currentTime * UInt64(info.numer) / UInt64(info.denom)
                self.in2startTime = Int(nanos)
                self.in2firstRun = false
            }
            do {
                let floatData = buffer.floatChannelData?.pointee
                for frame in 0..<buffer.frameLength{
                    if (self.buf2current + Int(frame)) < totalRecordSize{
                        self.in2Buf[self.buf2current + Int(frame)] = floatData![Int(frame)]
                    }
                }


                self.buf2current += Int(buffer.frameLength)
                if (self.numberOfSamples + Int(buffer.frameLength)) <= totalRecordSize{
                    try self.stimulusFile.write(from: buffer)
                    self.numberOfSamples += Int(buffer.frameLength)                } else {
                    self.engine.stop()
                    self.running = false
                }
            } catch {
                print(NSString(string: "write failed"))
            }
        })
    }


    let micAudioConverter = AVAudioConverter(from: inputFormat, to: stimulusFormat!)
    var micChannelMap:[NSNumber] = [0,-1]
    micAudioConverter?.channelMap = micChannelMap

    let refAudioConverter = AVAudioConverter(from: inputFormat, to: stimulusFormat!)
    var refChannelMap:[NSNumber] = [1,-1]
    refAudioConverter?.channelMap = refChannelMap



    //Measurement Tap
    engine.inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: inputFormat, block: {(buffer2: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time: AVAudioTime!) -> Void in
        //print(NSString(string:"writing"))

        if self.in1firstRun == true {
            var info = mach_timebase_info()
            mach_timebase_info(&info)
            let currentTime = mach_absolute_time()
            let nanos = currentTime * UInt64(info.numer) / UInt64(info.denom)
            self.in1StartTime = Int(nanos)
            self.in1firstRun = false
        }
        do {
            let micConvertedBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: stimulusFormat!, frameCapacity: buffer2.frameCapacity)
            let micInputBlock: AVAudioConverterInputBlock = { inNumPackets, outStatus in
                outStatus.pointee = AVAudioConverterInputStatus.haveData
                return buffer2
            }
            var error: NSError? = nil
            //let status = audioConverter.convert(to: convertedBuffer!, error: &error, withInputFrom: inputBlock)



            let status =  micAudioConverter?.convert(to: micConvertedBuffer!, error: &error, withInputFrom: micInputBlock)
            //print(status)
            let floatData = micConvertedBuffer?.floatChannelData?.pointee
            for frame in 0..<micConvertedBuffer!.frameLength{
                if (self.buf1current + Int(frame)) < totalRecordSize{
                self.in1Buf[self.buf1current + Int(frame)] = floatData![Int(frame)]

            }
                if (self.buf1current + Int(frame)) >= totalRecordSize {
                    self.engine.stop()
                    self.running = false
                }


            }
            self.buf1current += Int(micConvertedBuffer!.frameLength)
            try self.measurementFile.write(from: micConvertedBuffer!)

        } catch {
            print(NSString(string: "write failed"))
        }

        if internalRefLoop == false {
            if self.in2firstRun == true{
                var info = mach_timebase_info()
                mach_timebase_info(&info)
                let currentTime = mach_absolute_time()
                let nanos = currentTime * UInt64(info.numer) / UInt64(info.denom)
                self.in2startTime = Int(nanos)
                self.in2firstRun = false
            }
            do {
                let refConvertedBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: stimulusFormat!, frameCapacity: buffer2.frameCapacity)
                let refInputBlock: AVAudioConverterInputBlock = { inNumPackets, outStatus in
                    outStatus.pointee = AVAudioConverterInputStatus.haveData
                    return buffer2

                }

                var error: NSError? = nil

                let status =  refAudioConverter?.convert(to: refConvertedBuffer!, error: &error, withInputFrom: refInputBlock)
                //print(status)
                let floatData = refConvertedBuffer?.floatChannelData?.pointee
                for frame in 0..<refConvertedBuffer!.frameLength{
                    if (self.buf2current + Int(frame)) < totalRecordSize{
                        self.in2Buf[self.buf2current + Int(frame)] = floatData![Int(frame)]
                    }

                }
                if (self.numberOfSamples + Int(buffer2.frameLength)) <= totalRecordSize{
                    self.buf2current += Int(refConvertedBuffer!.frameLength)
                    try self.stimulusFile.write(from: refConvertedBuffer!)               } else {
                    self.engine.stop()
                    self.running = false
                }


            } catch {
                print(NSString(string: "write failed"))
            }
            }
        }
    )


    assert(engine.inputNode != nil)
    running = true
    try! engine.start()
```

So The above method is my entire class. Currently each buffer call on installTap writes the input directly to a WAV file. This is where I can see the two end results differing each time.  I have tried adding the startTime variable and subtracting the two, but the results still vary.

Do I need to take into account my output will have latency too that may vary with each call?  If so,  how do I add this time into the equation?  What I am looking for is for the two inputs and outputs to all have relative time, so that I can compare them.  The different hardware latency will not matter too much, as long as I can identify the end call times.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing real-time measurements, you might want to use `AVAudioSinkNode` instead of a Tap. The Sink Node is new and introduced along with AVAudioSourceNode you are using. With installing a Tap you won't be able to get precise timing.